# how many minutes left for a multiple of 5(05, 10, 15...) in python

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I take the time now, and I need to know how many minutes left for the next multiple minute of 5, for example, I use the function `now = datetime.now()` and returns `datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 2, 9, 33, 5, 478647)`, in this example, left 2 minutes for the 35 minutes, I need the program do that automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
time = datetime.datetime.now()
min = time.minute
left = 5-(min%5)
```

This will return 5 if the minute is a multiple of 5.